# Send XML file as response to ajax

Tags: ajax, jakarta-ee, servlets

i have created a xml file from database.
this xml file i need to send as a response from my servlet to ajax.
I have checked various forums and blogs over the web and found that the response xml is created at the time when the servlet is called.
In this case i already have a xml file in my server, i just need to send it as a response to ajax.

Help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your doGet() or doPost() method make sure you set the content-type **before** writing anything to the response. Like this...

```
PrintWriter pr = response.getWriter();
response.setContentType("application/xml");
//parse your data to XML
String xml = parseXml(root);
pr.write(xml);
```

*Note: A content-type of `"text/xml"` should also be valid. Frameworks like JQuery and Prototype support both.*